# Python scrapy run with Unhandled error in Deferred

Tags: python-2.7

windows python version is 2.7.10 scrapy version is 1.0.1
when i run scrapy fetch http://google.com:81 also appear this problem
and i don't konw how to solve it
my code:
items.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class StackItem(Item):


  title = Field()

  url = Field()
```

stack_spider.py

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class StackSpider(Spider):

  name = "stack"

  allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]



start_urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest", ]



 def parse(self, response):
questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/h3')

for question in questions:
  item = StackItem()
  item['title'] = question.xpath(
      'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').extract()[0]
  item['url'] = question.xpath(
      'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').extract()[0]
  yield item
```

the error detail:

```
$ scrapy crawl stack
2015-07-07 16:26:26 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: stack)

2015-07-07 16:26:26 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2015-07-07 16:26:26 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': `'stack.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'stack'}`

2015-07-07 16:26:27 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, `TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState`

Unhandled error in Deferred:

2015-07-07 16:26:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2015-07-07 16:26:28 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the `stack_spider.py` file you are missing a line:

`from stack.items import StackItem`